# 404 - File or directory not found. IIS Windows Authentication issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404, windows-authentication

I developed an asp.net website which had a login page for authentication. 
Now I have a requirement to remove the login page and implement windows authentication. I enabled Windows authentication in web.config file and in IIS Server Manager and made changes in the project. Locally the page works perfect, but when I try to access the home page from server, it shows this error:

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

If I access the link again, this time it will open the page. Also while working in the website, sometimes, the error message is shown randomly.

Comment: as you are using the Windows autentication then you no need of using the  FORM Autentication , is it Disabled ?

Comment: yes I disabled it.The issue is resolved.Thank you

Comment: will post it as answer please mark it as answer and also upvote it for fututre users

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the Windows authentication then you no need of using the `FORM Autentication` , You need to Disable it.